# Video Streaming Over Websockets

Tags: android, ios, websocket, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying to build mobile app which can stream video from both sides(i.e something like video calling).

I looked into webrtc, but thats not yet ready for mobile native apps as such and anyways what webrtc was doing was allowing browser to capture camera and audio directly without requiring plugins etc. But in native mobile apps capturing camera and audio isn't a issue and basically a very low latency and dual transport layer is needed. In many articles and places I read about using webrtc over websockets.

So I thought I can stream the video using websockets. Is it correct or am I missing anything?

I understand that there is one more difference that webrtc is directly client to client...whereas websocket would be client-server-client, is there anyway to avoid it. And what would that mean it terms of latency.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something.

- webRTC works very well on mobile. There are examples/white clients in the reference code (appRTCDEMO) at webrtc.org for both iOS and android, and multiple apps out there. Last one to have been announced was appear.in
- getting the video and audio stream from the stream is part of the
  media API and not webRTC API per say (getusermedia).
- webRTC is really the p2p connection (RTCPeerConnection: transport and firewall traversal) and the media engine (encoding, packeting, encrypting) of the equation and exactly what you re looking for.
- webSockets is just a transport mechanism. It does not handle firewall/nat traversal, media processing, and packeting/chunking that you would have then to implement at application level.
- as far as the *signaling* is concerned, webRTC does not specify/impose any protocol, and the seemingly usual way to do it is to set up a signaling server. The app usually connects to that server using web socket or XHR, or something else to do the original handshake/call set up. Many app abstracts this by using libraries like socket.io.

Comment: OK. Fine. Then why would I use webrtc over websockets? Websockets can also deliver the basic things I am looking for and since webrtc is not ready for use in native mobile apps. Why shouldn't I go with websocket? Yeah its not p2p but how much difference would that make in latency?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This solution can and does work for mobile browsers. But, I don't know if there exists all the software needed in an Android/IOS environment (even with something like React Native).

But, the solution can work. In fact, I've done it on a raspberry pi.

I basically just live stream an FFMPEG pipeline from a USB camera, pipe it to a UDP source, have a "relay" service that basically converts the UDP packets and transmits it to clients using engine.io from Javascript, then use this really sweet mpeg1 encoder on the web side of things to decode the web socket packets into a mpeg1 video.

So I pipe the ffmpeg stream doing something like: https://github.com/freefarmdata/auto_farm_recorder/blob/master/recorder/src/controllers/streams.py#L13

Then read the UDP stream and relay it to a Node app like:
https://github.com/freefarmdata/auto_farm_recorder/blob/master/relay/src/socket.js#L97

Then I decode the stream using something like:
https://github.com/freefarmdata/auto_farm_recorder/blob/master/web/src/app/widgets/LiveStream.js

Keep in mind that this is using TCP and not UDP as the protocol for data transfer. Which means that in order to keep the stream going, I have to make sure that my client has enough bandwidth for live streaming. If they don't, I can't use RTP or something to do QOS on my stream to reduce the quality level. I basically just have to drop packets which in turn will drop frames and cause strange corruption issues in the mpeg1 decoder.

You could theoretically do this with the engine.io service and send packets back and forth about the connection quality that will tell the "relay" server to start pulling from a different UDP source (one that is a lower bitrate).

But I digress.