# Streaming video real time

Tags: android, video, websocket, video-streaming, real-time

I have a special device (a sort of external video camera) which should send video in real time and streaming to a smartphone (android first). 
In other words imagine how GoPro app works, in which you are able to watch in real-time on your smartphone what camera is recording .

My question is, what kind of protocol should be used to get the real time video streaming? I though about WebSocket but I do not know if it is the best solution as alternative to HTTP.

I looking forward to hearing from you
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu sholud use [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) protocol. Depending on whether the codec uses your camera, you sholud use MediaPlayer class (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)) or use [VLC library](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/#libVLC_on_Android).

Comment: So you are talking about to use RTSP protocol on device's camera and use VLC library on smartphone. Have you any idea how it could works?

Comment: In what format, what codec your device's camera stream video? Do you know stream url? Your device have any stream settings?

Comment: I do not know man. Think that I am looking for a solution and I would like to use WebSocket, what do you think about it?

Comment: @ParideLetizia WebSockets is just a transport mechanism. It does not handle media processing, and packeting/chunking that you would have then to implement at application level. Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094410/video-streaming-over-websockets

Comment: Thank you @Sergey, but I really do not understand what I should use between WebSocket and WebRTC in order to making communication between a device (external webcam) and my smartphone. Could you help mi please?

Comment: @ParideLetizia i think, you should research your device settings/api - if your device can stream video, It must be a way to get the stream URL - something like rtsp://<ip-your device>:<port>/<url-to-stream>, usually you can find it by 1. connect your camera via USB/WiFi/etc to computer 2. open camera settings by camera settings URL from web-browser, for  example http://127.1.1.1 (see camera manual)  3. review/change camer settings, see, what you need to connet to your camera from web-browser/VLC player, for example  4. enjoy

Comment: Which a "special device" do you have?

Comment: It is a sort of video-camera which, through a click from smartphone, it is able to make a photo.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [RTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) you it is the protocol in the Android API

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mean video streaming and with the android.net.rtp class i would be able to manage the audio streaming